# Switch must be exhaustive in Xcode 12

Tags: swift, xcode12

in new Xcode 12, I am getting a peculiar error in permission scope.
**Switch must be exhaustive add .limited case.** Though I added .limited case its still showing this error. I am getting this on where ever switch cases is used. Can You point me in the right direction. I recently upgraded my project from Xcode 11 to Xcode 12 so am a bit confused here.

```
func openPhotoController(item: InfoItem) {
    
    
    let status = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
    
    switch status {
    case .authorized:
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async
        {
            let photoLib = photoLibViewController()
            photoLib.delegate = self
            photoLibCropImage = false
            photoLib.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
            photoLib.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            photoLib.allowMultipleSelection = false
            self.present(photoLib, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        print("authorized")
    //handle authorized status
    case .denied, .restricted :
        
        print("denied")
        
        AlertManager.showAlertView(title: "Alert?", subtitle: "Please allow access to your photo library to use this functionality", showCancelButton: true, okButtonTitle: "Go to Settings", cancelButtonTitle: "Cancel") {
            
            if let url = URL(string:UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)
            {
                if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url)
                {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    //handle denied status
    case .notDetermined:
        // ask for permissions
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                
                print("authorized")
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                    let photoLib = photoLibViewController()
                    photoLib.delegate = self
                    photoLibCropImage = false
                    photoLib.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
                    photoLib.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
                    photoLib.allowMultipleSelection = false
                    self.present(photoLib, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            // as above
            case .denied, .restricted:
                
                print("denied")
            // as above
            case .notDetermined:
                print("notDetermined")
            // won't happen but still
            case .limited:
                print("notDetermined")
            default:
                print("notDetermined")
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are 2 switches. The outer switch(parent switch) does not have 'case .limited'.

Comment: thanks was a bit panicked and forgot the basics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In **WWDC 2020**, **iOS 14** Apple introduced a new feature that will give limited access to the photo library. You are missing `.limited` case for outer main Switch. Your updated code:

```
switch PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus(for: .readWrite) {
case .notDetermined:
    // ask for access
case .restricted, .denied:
    // sorry
case .authorized:
    // we have full access
 
// new option: 
case .limited:
    // we only got access to a part of the library
}
```

For More, you can check [here](https://mackuba.eu/2020/07/07/photo-library-changes-ios-14/)

Answer (score 1):

Add `.limited` case for the outer switch.

If you don't want to handle it, you can always insert a default case (which you have for your inner switch, but don't have for the outer one):

```swift
...
default:
    // Otherwise, do something else
```

Doc on Swift switch: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html.